# Is there a settings option for a fully expanded settings menu in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intelephense

When I open this settings menu, and others of this type, there are always some menu items hidden and I have to scroll.

Is there a setting option to have these kinds of menus fully expanded without the need to scroll?

macOS Big Sur

Thanks

[image: Unexpanded menu screenshot]

Comment: it is more an OS setting than VSC, allow the OS to display context menus above the current mouse position

Comment: @rioV8 yeah, could be an OS setting although I would not call it a context menu (right click or cmd click) as it's a (left) click on an icon. At the moment I cannot see anywhere to change this or even know what it is called.

Comment: it is a menu, if it is shown by left-click or right click is up to the application, for the menu bar it has default behavior to respond to left click, but you can display a menu based on any event

Comment: It is a menu, I just don't think it's a 'context' menu. It's not the same as clicking a file or something in your code and getting a different menu based on the context. Anyway, it's splitting hairs, but the point is that I don't know what it is called, if it has a specific name, therefore struggling to search for a solution. Thanks for your contribution.